# Select Distinct for 2 columns in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

If I have a table such as

```
1 bob
1 ray
1 bob
1 ray
2 joe
2 joe
```

And I want to select distinct based on the two columns so that I would get

```
1 bob
1 ray
2 joe
```

How can I word my query? Is the only way to concatenate the columns and wrap them around a distinct function operator?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
select distinct id, name from [table]
```

or

```
select id, name from [table] group by id, name
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies, how come 47k is not enough?

Comment: The number is arbitrary - I could ask you why 100 is not enough.  Me, I've learnt a fair bit while sharpening skills.  The SO format works better than traditional forums.

Comment: and @OMG Ponies: "You can never get enough of what you don't need to make you happy."  ~Eric Hoffer :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can just do:

```
select distinct col1, col2 from your_table;
```

That's exactly what the **distinct** operator is for: removing duplicate result rows.

Keep in mind that **distinct** is usually a pretty expensive operation, since, after processing the query, the DB server might perform a **sort** operation in order to remove the duplicates.